# Check whether an array in the inspector is empty

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I have a public array that should be filled in the inspector, and I want to do something if that array is empty. 
That array is empty in the inspector "size = 0"

```
public GameObject[] objects;

    void CheckArray ()
    {
        if (objects.Length < 0 ) // this doesn't work
        {
            Debug.Log("Empty!");  
        }
        else 
        {
            Debug.Log("Not Empty"); // this gets logged out
        }
    }
```

The above doesn't work, I tried something else but also doesn't work:

```
void CheckArray ()
    {
        if (objects == null ) // this doesn't work
        {
            Debug.Log("Empty!");  
        }
        else 
        {
            Debug.Log("Not Empty");  // this gets logged out
        }
    }
```

Comment: What output are you expecting in your Debug Log when `objects.Length` is `0` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your if statement `if (objects.Length < 0 )` is wrong.

Array is usually `0` when empty. When it is `0`, `if (objects.Length < 0 )` will never be true because you are checking if array length is less than `0` instead of if array length is equals to `0`..

That should be `if (objects.Length == 0 )` or `if (objects.Length <= 0 )`

EDIT:

> Ok this worked but it doesn't make any sense to me, because when I add
>   an object and check for "objects[0]" it returns that object, meaning
>   an array with 1 object in it will be indexed at 0, but at the same
>   time a "Length" of 0 means it's empty?

There is an array size, there are elements. When I say empty, I meant not setting the **size** from the Editor. Since `objects` is a public variable, Editor will give it default value of `0`. That `0` is what I meant when I say empty array.The `Debug.Log(objects.Length);` will output `0`.

Empty array:

[image]

Non Empty Array:

[image]

In this case, `Debug.Log(objects.Length);` should print 3 even though that *Element 1* is `null` or nothing is assigned to it. `objects.Length` will always equals to the size set in the Editor.

```
GameObject camera = objects[0];
GameObject someObj = objects[1]; //ELEMENT IS NULL
GameObject dLight = objects[2];
```

Want to check if each *individual* element is null?

```
for (int i = 0; i < objects.Length; i++)
{
    if (objects[i] == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Empty!: " + i);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Not Empty: " + i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok this worked but it doesn't make any sense to me, because when I add an object and check for "objects[0]" it returns that object, meaning an array with 1 object in it will be indexed at 0, but at the same time a "Length" of 0 means it's empty?!

Comment: Modified the answer to answer this. `objects.Length` is always the amount of the array size set in the Editor whether something is plugged to the slot or not. Probably confused your more.